# Set class variable from interface implemented function and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask

Correct the title if you think it does not descibe the question correctly.

I want to set a class variable through an implemented interface and return it to another class that calls this function.

**Here is the code. I use the straight forward combination of AsyncTask and Interface to return an object from onPostExecute:**

```
public boolean isUserLoggedIn() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", is_user_logged_in_tag));
    jsonParser = new DbHandler(new DBinterface() {
        @Override
        public void onRemoteCallComplete(JSONObject jsonFromNet) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            if (Integer.parseInt(jsonFromNet.getString("num_rows")) > 0) {
                isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                isLoggedIn = false;
            }
        }
    }, params).execute();
    System.out.println("DEBUG[10] " + isLoggedIn);
    return isLoggedIn;
}
```

**isLoggedIn is declared as:**

> private boolean isLoggedIn = false;

**So i use this function from another class to check if user is logged in:**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity { 

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions(this);


            userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn();

        try {
            if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn()){
             //It nevers enters here as isUserLoggedIn always return the initial FALSE value.                              
                setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
                btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
.....
.....
}
```

My problem is that isLoggedIn remains **always** false, as i use AsyncTask to query the database to check if user is logged in. It does not work even with the use of get() method.

**The onPostExecute of the AsyncTask:**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
    try {
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(1));
        intf.onRemoteCallComplete(jsonObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dummy_layout);
        // Check login status in database

        userFunctions = new UserFunctions(this);

        try {
            userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(this);
...
...
}

@Override
public void onRemoteCallComplete(JSONObject jsonFromNet) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    checkUserState(jsonFromNet.getString("num_rows"));
}


private void checkUserState(String num_rows) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(num_rows) > 0) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(new MyCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRemoteCallComplete(JSONObject jsonFromNet) throws JSONException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

                        }
                    });
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    } else {
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
}
```

and this is isUserLoggedIn that got simplified:

```
public void isUserLoggedIn(MyCallback callback) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", is_user_logged_in_tag));
    jsonParser = (DbHandler) new DbHandler(activity, callback, params).execute();
}
```

Comment: Because the AsyncTask hasn't finished yet?

Comment: Yes i know. This is why i ask for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `isUserLoggedIn()` method returns with the current status immediately, but it has kicked off `DbHandler` in the process.  So the caller of `isUserLoggedIn()` is not waiting for the result.  Rework your `Activity` code to run a check on login status (so revise `isUserLoggedIn()` to be `checkUserLoginStatus()`.  In the `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` you'd need to "notify" the `Activity` of the up to date status.  Be careful here as you'll need to make sure your `AsyncTask` is carefully coordinated with the lifecycle of your `Activity`.  It is not lifecycle aware, so it's possible to get `IllegalStateException` if you attempt to manipulate UI components directly if the `Activity` is not in the running state.

Comment: I will try to rework my code based on your answer. The problem is that I do not want to change asynctask because it is used for several tasks.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give some code examples

Comment: @ManosKontakis try this article and see if it helps w/understanding `AsyncTask` and using it: http://po.st/Cei3m2

Comment: Thank you i will! Do i have to pass to AsyncTask the activity object to notify the activity about the users' status?

Comment: There's a few different ways to handle it, such as using `Activity` directly, using a `WeakReference` to it or using a callback interface.  If you allow the `AsyncTask` to have a strong reference to the `Activity` then you could potentially cause a memory leak.  But, if you carefully coordinate w/`onPause()` then it can be done.

Comment: Which method do you think is the best to implement it? Its the first time i hear about WeakReference, i will google it. I would be pleased if you could provide a code example! I want to implement it using the most efficient way and not 'hacks'

Comment: @ManosKontakis The efficient way would be to let the interface do the communicating.

Comment: @ManosKontakis I've used all 3 of the above methods, they'll all work fine.  In any one of the cases you'll have to coordinate with lifecycle.  It's not hard to do.  My apologies, I don't have a simple project handy which uses them I can point you at.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach, good work.  Be sure to hook your `onPause()` method of the `Activity` and track your `AsyncTask` (`UserFunctions`) so you can call `.cancel()` on it.  Otherwise your `AsyncTask` could complete after pause and cause a crash.

Answer (score -2):

You can store the variable in the stored preferences.

In the post execute of the async task , if log in is positive store the result like so :

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("LOGGEDIN", "1");
    editor.commit();
```

then read your variable like so :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String loggedin = sharedPref.getString("LOGGEDIN"), "0");
```

Setup up the above read in a private method to check for logIn which returns boolean isLoggedIn.